# Using FILTER where I return only the exact match?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a Google sheets spreadsheet that looks as follows:

[image]

Using a combination of FILTER and SEARCH:

```
=FILTER(RawData!A2:D5546, SEARCH(B1, RawData!A2:A5546), 
 SEARCH(C1, RawData!A2:A5546), 
 SEARCH(D1, RawData!A2:A5546), 
 SEARCH(E1, RawData!A2:A5546)
)
```

I can search the raw lists (yellow) and get the output (blue). However, the formula above will return BOTH of A2 and A3.

What I am trying to get going is that:

- Given a set of search inputs (green)
- It will search the raw lists (yellow)
- Returning (blue) only lists that match exactly with respect to:
- a) Exact same order of items in green to yellow
- b) All the items per list (yellow) are found in the search parameters (green)

So the above example blue is the expected result ie only A2 (not A1 and A2). Can anyone give me any suggestions on how I can accomplish this with a formula? While I could write it in script I am hoping to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=FILTER(RawData!A2:A, 
 REGEXMATCH(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(RawData!A2:A, CHAR(10)), "[a-zA-Z]+"))),,999^99))), 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, B1:E1)&"$"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: player0:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OQYA1IoLFHkNh8XXHCHazJuLm8brKX8wHiDfQEmHaTM/edit?usp=sharing. I have a search in there that should return only A2 but returns nothing?

Comment: player0: If you have a moment - for the life of me I still cannot see why your code is not working